# Cinemachine Collider not working, should the structures in Collide Against have Colliders?

Tags: unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I have a freelook camera, and added the extension of Cinemachine Collider.
I've set all my structures in the scene into CameraCollider layer, chosen this layer in "Collide Against" option under the Obstacle Detection of the extension, and used the Pull Camera Forward strategy.
(I've also set Near Clip Plane to 0.01 under Lens)

This doesn't work, and camera doesn't move forward when it hits a structure. I'm using Unity 2019.4 and Cinemachine 2.6.3.

Should I add colliders to my structures?

[image: Extension Screenshot]

[image: Structure Screenshot]

Please help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I know what's happening, I really need to add colliders to my structures, and the size of the colliders need to be adjusted so they are not so small.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the response, the way to solve this is to add colliders to your structures, and it wouldn't hurt setting those collider's z axis just a bit wider than the graphics